# Google Spreadsheet - store data from PHP form

Tags: authorization, google-sheets-api

I want to store form record into spreadsheet. What type of authorization should I use in google spreadsheets and how to make it work - so i do not have to authorize script to access the spreadsheet.

I could not find working example. I use OAuth2.0 But it wants me to be logged and have access to spreadsheet when I submit form and want to store data.

Thanks for advice or an example

Paul